# SSMS navigate with arrow keys through objects

Tags: sql-server, ssms, ssms-2017

Is it possible to navigate through SSMS Object Explorer objects using arrow keys?

Comment: @EzLo I just found that. I edited my question. I still cannot browse through its items with arrow keys. Thank you:-)